# PHP and SOAP integration

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I connected to a SOAP server from a client and am trying to send form information back.

The connection works, but I have no idea how to send data back. I have received documentation ( -> http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=89258359616332514672) and am stuck at the function `AddApplication`

This is the PHP code I've written so far. There is no form integration yet, only dummy data.

```
    <?

    $client = new SoapClient(
        'https://wstest.hrweb.be/TvBastards/TvBastards/Job.svc?singleWsdl',
        array(
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1
        )
    );

    $params = array(
        'username' => 'XXX',
        'password' => 'XXX',
        'environmentKey' => 'XXX',
    );

    //Open session
    try{
        $token = $client->OpenSession($params);
    }catch(SoapFault $ex){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($ex->detail->ExceptionDetail);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    //Add Application
    try{
        $resp = $client->AddApplication($params, ___THE_XML_SHOULD_BE_HERE___); // I have no idea how I can implement a XML file over here, and make this part work
    }catch(SoapFault $ex){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($ex->detail->ExceptionDetail);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    //Close session
    try{
        $app = $client->CloseSession($token);
    }catch(SoapFault $ex){
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($ex);
        echo "</pre>";      
    }`
```

The error I receive now is the following:

```
End element 'Body' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' expected. Found element 'param1' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 156.
```

Which is understandable as I don't provide any XML.

I receive my token so the `OpenSession` works perfectly. As said, I'm completely stuck at the `AddApplication` function. This is my first encounter with a SOAP service, so every possible bit of explanation is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, and hopefully it can help out some others. I'll try and put it into steps.

```
define('SIM_LOGIN', 'LOGIN NAME HERE');
define('SIM_PASSWORD', 'LOGIN PASSWORD HERE');
define('ENV_KEY', 'ENVIRONMENT KEY HERE');

/*** login parameters ***/
$params = array(
  'username' => SIM_LOGIN,
  'password' => SIM_PASSWORD,
  'environmentKey' => ENV_KEY,
);

/*** Set up client ***/
$client = new SoapClient(
  __SOAP URL HERE__,
  array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1
  )
);
```

After setting up the parameters and connecting to the client, we can start calling functions within the SOAP service. Every SOAP service will be different, so function names and parameters can be different. In below example I need to open a session to retrieve a token. This token is used in all the other functions, so this function is necessary. If something fails I call the "abort()" function.

```
try{
  $token = $client->OpenSession($params);
}catch(SoapFault $ex){
  abort();
}
```

If the token is received I call upon the function AddApplication. This expects the token parameter and an "object" (which is basically an STDClass).

I create an stdClass with all my data:

```
/*** Create stdClass with requested data ***/
$std = new stdClass();

$std->Firstname           = $firstname;
$std->Lastname            = $lastname;
$std->Birthdate           = $birthdate;
$std->Phone               = $phone;
$std->Email               = $email;
```

Be sure to check camelcasing of names or capitals, as this makes all the difference.

Now we call upon the AddApplication function with parameters "token(string)" and "application(object)".

```
/*** AddApplication ***/
try{
  $result = $client->AddApplication(array("token" => $token, "application" => $std));
}catch(SoapFault $ex){
    abort();
}
```

If all goes well the data is stored on the external server and you receive a "success" message. It's possible that you receive a "fail" even without going into the SoapFault. Be sure to log both "$result" and "$ex", as a SOAP service can return a "Fail" but the try-catch sees this as a well formed result.

Last thing to do is close the session (and destroy the token)

```
/*** CloseSession ***/
try{
  $app = $client->CloseSession($token);
}catch(SoapFault $ex){
  abort();
}
```

If any questions, don't hesitate to ask them here, I'll be glad to help as I had such problems figuring this out.